# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10684; index=10684

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In my Android Project, I'm trying to use `PolyUtil.decode` to draw a polyline on google map using a response from google maps API.

Here is the code I've used for this :

```java
    public void gettingDerictions(double sourceLat, double sourceLong, double destLat, double destLong) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + sourceLat + "," + sourceLong + "&destination=" + destLat + "," + destLong + "&key=****************************";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        Log.e("The response", response);
                        List<LatLng> route = PolyUtil.decode(response);
                        System.out.println(route);
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("The response", "it didn't work");
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);

            }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
07-31 22:04:13.486 21530-21530/com.innoventiq.arkbeh E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.innoventiq.arkbeh, PID: 21530
    java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10684; index=10684
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
        at com.google.maps.android.PolyUtil.decode(PolyUtil.java:464)
        at com.innoventiq.arkbeh.MapsActivity$6.onResponse(MapsActivity.java:260)
        at com.innoventiq.arkbeh.MapsActivity$6.onResponse(MapsActivity.java:255)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the value of `response`.

```
{
       "geocoded_waypoints" : [
          {
             "geocoder_status" : "OK",
             "place_id" : "Ek82IFJpY2ggSG9tZSwgQWwgQWdhbXkgQWwgQmFocmksIFFlc20gQWQgRGVraGlsYWgsIEFsZXhhbmRyaWEgR292ZXJub3JhdGUsIEVneXB0IhoSGAoUChIJv3T_1uiU9RQR7X1tYzsaZ8QQBg",
             "types" : [ "street_address" ]
          },
          {
             "geocoder_status" : "OK",
             "place_id" : "ChIJ83j9iddBWBQR3SDSTdvOCbk",
             "types" : [ "airport", "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
          }
       ],
       "routes" : [
          {
             "bounds" : {
                "northeast" : {
                   "lat" : 31.1095921,
                   "lng" : 31.2352784
                },
                "southwest" : {
                   "lat" : 30.0439783,
                   "lng" : 29.7347456
                }
             },
             "copyrights" : "Map data ©2019 ORION-ME",
             "legs" : [
                {
                   "distance" : {
                      "text" : "206 km",
                      "value" : 206160
                   },
                   "duration" : {
                      "text" : "2 hours 29 mins",
                      "value" : 8967
                   },
                   "end_address" : "Nasser, Madinaty, محافظة القاهرة‬ 11566, Egypt",
                   "end_location" : {
                      "lat" : 30.0445393,
                      "lng" : 31.2352658
                   },
                   "start_address" : "6 Rich Home, Al Agamy Al Bahri, Qesm Ad Dekhilah, Alexandria Governorate, Egypt",
                   "start_location" : {
                      "lat" : 31.1092252,
                      "lng" : 29.7598111
                   },
                   "steps" : [
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "57 m",
                            "value" : 57
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "1 min",
                            "value" : 15
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 31.1089022,
                            "lng" : 29.7602755
                         },
                         "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003esoutheast\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eRich Home\u003c/b\u003e",
                         "polyline" : {
                            "points" : "u_{|DymstDLU`@q@PU"
                         },
                         "start_location" : {
                            "lat" : 31.1092252,
                            "lng" : 29.7598111
                         },
                         "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                      },
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "0.1 km",
                            "value" : 106
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "1 min",
                            "value" : 41
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 31.1095921,
                            "lng" : 29.7610398
                         },
                         "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eRich Home\u003c/b\u003e",
                         "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                         "polyline" : {
                            "points" : "s}z|DwpstDIKu@cAiAgA"
                         },
                         "start_location" : {
                            "lat" : 31.1089022,
                            "lng" : 29.7602755
                         },
                         "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                      },
                      {
                         "distance" : {
                            "text" : "1.6 km",
                            "value" : 1553
                         },
                         "duration" : {
                            "text" : "8 mins",
                            "value" : 485
                         },
                         "end_location" : {
                            "lat" : 31.0988067,
                            "lng" : 29.7712707
                         },
```

Comment: The last index of a string with length 10684 is 10683 (since the first is 0). Maybe this is not what you are asking, but your title isn't very good if not.

Comment: Add to your post the value of response. Add also comment out the line **List<LatLng> route = PolyUtil.decode(response)** because you are passing the wrong value to decode which causes the crash.

Comment: @GiddyNaya added the value of response to the question, Also when removing the `List<LatLng> route = PolyUtil.decode(response)` it is not crashing but can't change it to list to use to draw a `polyline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response object is not well formatted before decoding. Try below implementation

```
public void gettingDerictions(double sourceLat, double sourceLong, double destLat, double destLong) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + sourceLat + "," + sourceLong + "&destination=" + destLat + "," + destLong + "&key=****************************";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                       // Log.e("The response", response);
                       // List<LatLng> route = PolyUtil.decode(response);
                       // System.out.println(route);

                      List<LatLng> movements = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                     try{
                      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                       //Retrieve routes from response
                      JSONObject jsonRoute = json.getJSONArray("routes").getJSONObject(0);
                       //Retrieve legs from routes 
                      JSONObject legs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs").getJSONObject(0);
                       //Retrieve steps from legs
                      JSONArray steps = legs.getJSONArray("steps");
                      final int numSteps = steps.length();
                      JSONObject step;
                       //Retrieve points from steps
                      for (int i = 0; i < numSteps; i++) {
                       step = steps.getJSONObject(i);
                       String pontos = step.getJSONObject("polyline").getString("points");
                       movements.addAll(PolyUtil.decode(pontos));
                      }
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                      Log.d("DirectionErr",ex.getMessage());
                    }

                       //make use of movements object here
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("The response", "it didn't work");
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);

            }
```

Comment: Log the value **json.getJSONArray("routes")** before initializing **jsonRoute** and confirm the value in it because response may not always return the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
I just realized there is an easier way to fix this. If you are getting your response in json then you should use `JsonObjectRequest` instead of String request, it will give you properly encoded Json that you can parse to String.

**OLD ANSWER**:.

This must have been caused by Escape Characters during encoding/decoding since you are using string.

Just remove unescape characters and it should work:

```
response  = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(polyLine);
```

There is an implementation of StringEscapeUtils in Apache commons-text, you can use it from here:

https://github.com/apache/commons-text/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.java

Comment: `Cannot resolve symbol 'StringEscapeUtils'` and it is not importable !!

Comment: @AhmedWagdi I just wrote it as an arbitrary file that you would use to unescape, there is an implementation available in Apache Commons Lang, I'll look for better option for you

Comment: @AhmedWagdi I've included a link to class file.

Comment: @AhmadWagdi using JsonObjectRequest instead of StringRequest will fix your issue.